# eventListeners Won't Leave

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

These are the last two lines of action script for my frame :

```
removeListeners();
if(!stage.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)){trace("STAGE HAS NO eventListeners");}
```

With the removeListeners() function having been described previously as :

```
function removeListeners(){
    if(button){
        button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,leaveGameScene);        
    }
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,menuOnFrame);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,collectDrachmas);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateHealth);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateCards);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateQuestions);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE,stageDeactivate);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,key_down);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,key_up);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,charEnterFrame);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateInteractives);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrameBadguy);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrameStage);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateConversations);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updatePit);
    //etc etc etc

}
```

Thus thoroughly removing any possible existing eventListeners that occur throughout my project. We know that no eventListeners are added multiple times, because of the reason given below and because all existing eventListeners are terminated with this code upon exiting a frame.

All eventListeners through my project are simply declared and are not added within other functions or anything like that (ex shown below), therefore removing the possibility of this problem originating from having multiples of the same eventListeners :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,updateHealth);
```

When the last two lines of the action script for my frame are executed, Flash acts as though there are absolutely no ENTER_FRAME eventListeners on the stage, tracing stubbornly that

`"STAGE HAS NO eventListeners"`

accordingly. However, after running through the code on this frame multiple ENTER_FRAME eventListeners of the stage are run that had been declared on the previous frame (this causes multiple errors, since currently null objects are being called upon)! The eventListener seems to reappear out of no where and no cause. How can this be possible? What could be the root of this problem?

Perhaps I should mention that I used the exact same method with a button to advance to this frame without trouble. Both ways end with :

```
removeListeners();
gotoAndPlay(1,"Menu");
```

**Update**

Here are the errors given :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/collectDrachmas()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:369]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/updateHealth()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:417]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/updateQuestions()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:592]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/updateCards()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:810]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/charEnterFrame()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:978]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/updateInteractives()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:1892]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/onFrameBadguy()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:2015]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/onFrameStage()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:2638]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at _109_fla::MainTimeline/updateConversations()[_109_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:2760]
```

These errors occur on account of the following eventListeners in their respective functions:

```
function collectDrachmas(e:Event)
function updateHealth(e:Event)
function updateCards(e:Event)
function charEnterFrame(e:Event)
function updateInteractives(e:Event)
function onFrameBadguy(e:Event)
function onFrameStage(e:Event)
function updateConversations(e:Event)
```

Comment: Can you share your fla,  that would be easiest to figure out what is going on.   I can tell you that it would be much better to have one unified ENTER_FRAME listener instead of the dozen or so you have.

Comment: OMG, why do you add so many listeners? You should group all those ENTER_FRAME handlers into one.

Comment: Should I though? I'll merge them all together and see if that simplifies things down

Comment: in the mean time though I'm open to any advice on what on earth the problem could be; recently I've been running into all kinds of strange problems, and usually the problem isn't in my code but is because of some strange exception or unexpected flash behavior that I would never have guessed.

Comment: You haven't shared enough for anyone to know what the problem is.  If replying to a comment,  use @username so they get an alert.

Comment: What listeners are executed unexpectedly? Post all code that adds them. Your "better save than sorry, let's remove every listener that could possibly ever be added"- type of approach hints on that you lost track of what is exactly happening. But for now, post the listeners that are executed unexpectedly and how you add them.

Comment: ok, errors occur on nearly all of the eventListeners, which shows that the eventListeners haven't really been removed, even though it previously said that the stage contains no onFrame eventListeners. But literally all the eventListeners that pop up out of no where are stage onFrame eventListeners @null

Comment: @Batman I didn't want to post all the code because it would be overwhelming and would discourage anyone trying to help me out, so I did my best to boil it down to the real problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying to provide readable, related code, +1 for that. However, it looks like the code in your question so far is not sufficient. I think we should take a step back and start from the ground up. Post the actual error messages that you receive, just so we are all on the same page of what's going on.

Comment: alright. And once again thank you both for your support. I'll post the errors in the question @null

Comment: please try to ping (using the @ with the username) either me or @Batman when reporting about changes, otherwise, your question will be forgotten. Ok, you have the line numbers, next up would be to see what is null in those line numbers. your best bet would be to place a breakpoint at these lines and when the debugger stops there, take a look at the variables. This is just to verify that this is really caused by unavailable objects that are on a previous frame. In addition to that, find all the places that add those listeners. Providing the fla file might also help, but I for one cannot open it

Comment: Well, after quite a few hours last night I managed to move all my onFrame eventListeners over to one eventListener with a few tricks to keep things in place. And by George, everything's working fine! However, I'm still convinced that Flash was doing something strange earlier, but honestly who cares? Things are working again now and if reorganizing eventListeners does the trick then that's fine with me. @null and Batman you both instructed me to unify the eventListeners to one, so if one of you would post that answer I'll reward you the answer. Thanks to both of you! Cheers

Comment: @Batman you were the first to comment, you shall be the one to answer

Comment: @null - I don't have time to write a good answer, plus there isn't really a clear answer to the problem, only the efficiency tip/advice of amalgamating all the enter frame handler (which is valuable to the question I suppose).  Go ahead though if you're so inclined to write up something and have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get an idea about your problem. But here is my understanding about it.

1. stage is a global object. So wherever or whenever you add eventlistener to that object it's listening to the same object. So be care about it.
2. also using different function for the same event for the same object is a bad idea.
3. Enterframe is a nasty thing in my experience .
4. The *stage* global is accessible to the code only after the display object is added to the stage. That means if you are going to use the stage object inside a class constructer most probable it will throw a null error. Which means we are accessing the object before it available to you. So in you case you may be trying to access the stage object before it's available to you.

Please share some more code so that we could get an idea of whats happening. Then definitely we could help you on this.

Comment: Your point 2 is what null and Batman had both encouraged, which saved my code. I have no idea why it would make a difference, but honestly who cares. The most important goal that we're trying to achieve is to make the code do what you want so I'm satisfied. You're the first to put that point in an answer, so I suppose you deserve the correct answer.